# why can't show the view after the function addview() in the constructor of a class which extend RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

I have implemented a custom view that extends RelatviewLayout, and add other views in the constructor. But it is wrong to show nothing. Is it wrong that addview() in the constrcutor?

**ThreePointTitle,java**

```
public class ThreePointTitle extends RelativeLayout {
/** return **/
private ImageView mLeft;
/** title **/
private TextView mTitle;
/** text(option) **/
private TextView mRight;

public ThreePointTitle(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mLeft = new ImageView(context);
    mLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.three_point_left_arrow);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams leftParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    leftParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, TRUE);
    leftParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, TRUE);
    if (showLeft()) {
        mLeft.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mLeft.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
    addView(mLeft, leftParams);

    mTitle = new TextView(context);
    mTitle.setTextSize(R.dimen.text_size_middle);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams centerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    centerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, TRUE);
    addView(mTitle, centerParams);

    mRight = new TextView(context);
    mRight.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sky_blue));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rightParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, TRUE);
    rightParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, TRUE);
    if (showRight()) {
        mRight.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mRight.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
    addView(mRight, rightParams);
}}
```

but it just show the left imageview but not the center title thought the showLeft() return true?

Comment: there are 2 or 3 more constructors for this class, you should override all of them. I think that you overriden wrong constructor

Comment: yes, you should implement and override all constructors if you build a custom view...

Comment: It is strange that it can show the left ImageView i have added. I tried to override the function onDraw() of the center title and it won't be called after onMeasure().

Comment: Ok, I know what is my problem. mTitle.setTextSize(R.dimen.text_size_middle makes it bigger than father view so that it doesn't show the text. And the correct one is mTitle.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_middle));